# Output HTML tags in PHP

Tags: php, html

The below code outputs the correct result:

```
<div class="top-bar">
    <div class="top-bar-left">
      <ul class="menu">
         <li class="menu-text">Messages</li>
         <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Send Friend Requests</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Accept Friend Requests</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
 </div>

 <div class="callout large primary">
    <div class="row column text-center">
       <h1>Home Page</h1>
       <h2 class="subheader">View Neighborhood, Block, and Friend Messages</h2>
     </div>
 </div>
```

But, when I copy these tags in the PHP tags and place echo in front of each line as shown below, the output is incorrect.

```
echo '<div class="top-bar">';
    echo '<div class="top-bar-left">';
    echo '<ul class="menu">';
    echo '<li class="menu-text">Messages</li>';
    echo '<li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>';
    echo '<li><a href="#">Send Friend Requests</a></li>';
    echo '<li><a href="#">Accept Friend Requests</a></li>';
    echo '</ul>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
```

[image]

Comment: is there any include lines before this ?

Comment: You need an HTTP server which knows how to deal with PHP. Just opening a PHP file in a browser is not enough.

Comment: also check the file extension..check whether it is still`.html`. It has to be `.php`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo '
<div class="top-bar">
<div class="top-bar-left">
<ul class="menu">
<li class="menu-text">Messages</li>
<li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Send Friend Requests</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Accept Friend Requests</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>';
```

That is a lot cleaner.
Also, is the file you are using a .php or .html file? If you use .html, it will never work!

Answer (score 3):

I see you are new into PHP.
This should work, but the PHP code will only run if you open the tags, like this:

```
<?php

echo '<div class="top-bar">';
echo '<div class="top-bar-left">';
echo '<ul class="menu">';
echo '<li class="menu-text">Messages</li>';
echo '<li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>';
echo '<li><a href="#">Send Friend Requests</a></li>';
echo '<li><a href="#">Accept Friend Requests</a></li>';
echo '</ul>';
echo '</div>';
echo '</div>';

?>
```

Remember that the file extension must be PHP or your web server won't recognize it as a PHP program.